# Dropped an EHD and corrupted it, now what?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, repair

I dropped a Seagate 3 tb EHD about a foot or so and now it's corrupted. Sometimes the drive shows up and sometimes it doesn't. When it does I can sometimes access the files briefly but then it seems like it disconnects and reconnects. Not sure what to do now, Im having windows scan and repair it but its taking a while.

Comment: There likely isn't anything you can do.  If the drive was running when it was dropped I guarantee you there was physical damage done to it.

Comment: Well it was running but not writing, not sure how much of a difference it makes. I highly doubt there is nothing that can be done though.

Comment: You have damaged the drive.  There is physical damage based on what you describe.  It powering up and then powering down when you attempt to access files is a sign of that damage.  The fact it wasn't writing data means nothing if the head was moving.

Comment: It doesn't power down, I think it just disconnects and reconnects. Physical damage doesn't mean it can't be recovered somehow though, if that is the case.

Comment: As I said I can see the data on occasion, if you have a real suggestion do share.

Comment: g-forces from dropping hard drives a foot or more onto a hard surface are enough to totally destroy them (actually a lot less than a foot for fatal damage, see drop table in linked image below). They may be able to handle 200G while unpowered, if it was running, a whole lot less. You'll have to read it while it's readable, get as much off as you can and then take it out to the front drive and finish it off with a hammer. Why you don't drop hard drives --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/AYD4D.png

Comment: Well thats pretty sobering. I've been listening to it and I hear no irregularities though, I'm going to see if I can remove it from its shelter and connect it through other means.

Comment: @FiascoLabs: It's my understanding that Seagate hard drives (as of the 15th generation) are designed to withstand maximum non-operating shock of 350 Gs. Operating shock is limited to 80 Gs. http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/docs/manual/desktop/Desktop%20HDD%20Gen%2015/100710254-rev-c.pdf

Comment: @DragonLord - And if you consult the chart, it's way too easy to exceed the 350G limit. 2 inches onto a Formica counter top will do it.

Comment: What does it mean if it doesn't sound like there is anything wrong? Should I try the freezer trick?

Comment: @Alex - it means that there was circuit damage, a connector came loose, or the heads got knocked far enough out of alignment that nothing makes sense to the head position control functions. At this point, you don't have to ask our permission, you can try anything you've heard will even marginally work, the drive is already defunct and probably can't really be damaged any further. Sometimes recovery is a Sisyphean task, no matter how much you roll the boulder, you get no results. You're in that territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw out the old one as it is incapable of RELIABLY storing data anymore.  Buy a replacement one and restore your data from your backups.

You do backups don't you...?

PS. This is why I like NAS boxes.  Once you've installed your NAS box you don't pick it up to plug it in to your laptop or your friend's or whatever, and hence there's a significant reduction in chances of it being dropped.

PPS.  If you insist on trying to recover some data from there yourself, do as little as you can to get the data.  Do not just keep trying various things.  All of the trying will usually make the drive worse.  If the data is that valuable that you're prepared to pay professionals to recovery your data, do so now, don't try a few things yourself first.

If however you just want to have a go yourself start with something like [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) that tries to read the disk and write a copy to somewhere else.  Then you can see if you can piece together what data the drive was able to read without relying on the disk keeping going.

Comment: not all of the data, because the drive was so big. However that doesn't answer what to do with the drive itself.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not about to call it quits when I can access and see the data.

Comment: How much storage would something like that require?

Comment: Usually it will require a disk at least the same size as the original.  Though some tools will use less.  If you don't have a spare disk that size right now.  Stop your attempts and go and buy your replacement disk, then use that to try and recover your data.